# What impacts aggregation in KPL for a Spark job?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-kinesis

I run Spark jobs to write to Kinesis via KPL, and I recently upgraded my KPL from 1.8.10 to 1.14.x. Previously, my job resulted in 1 Kinesis record with 20 user records. After the upgrade, there are now 20 Kinesis records with 1 user record each. I'm trying to understand why these user records are not aggregating enough / at all after the KPL upgrade.

I opened up Spark History Server and see that the number of executors / tasks is the same between the Spark jobs before and after the upgrade, and I spot checked some of the Spark logical/physical query plans which look very similar as well. I'm a bit lost at this point and would appreciate any pointers - is aggregation configurable via KPL config, what impacts it (I figured the Spark plan would e.g tasks/executors), etc.